# Program on GD32f103 microcontroller runs only with debugger attached, won't run after reset

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, microcontroller

I'm using a J-Link EDU Mini debugger/programmer, to upload a simple test program to a GD32f103 microcontroller (the ST32f103 clone/copy). The program is a mere test program, meant to turn an LED on. It's written in SMT32CubeIDE, and here, it is based on the ST32f103.

After uploading the compiled .elf file to the GD32f103 using the J-Kink, the LED turns on just fine. However, once I detach the J-Link and reset the processor, the program appears not to boot, because the LED won't turn on.

What can the source of this problem be?

Comment: Make sure you use a flash build and not some RAM build.

Comment: @Lundin, this is the first time I'm reading about this, so I'm not sure what you mean. :(

Comment: Many IDEs have a debug build where your code is downloaded to RAM for the sole purpose to be executed from a debugger during development. This saves download times and a tiny bit of flash wear but that's about it. The release build however will download the program in flash where it persists after cycling power. I personally recommend to always use a flash build even when doing debug builds. There's various bugs like missing wait states etc that only surface when you execute from flash.

Comment: @Lundin, we've assumed that this is something we change from "Project > Build Configurations > Set Active > 2 Release", as opposed to "1 Debug", from within the STM32CubeIDE project. So we did that, rebuilt, but apart from the fact that there's now no communication with the J-Link, the behavior is the same. The LED turns on after loading the program, but won't after detaching the debugger and pressing reset.

Comment: Is the watchdog on? How is it handled - where do you end up after a watchdog reset? Are you using low-voltage detect and where do you end up after a LVD reset? Status of the reset pin when you look at it with a scope, do you get continuous interrupts? (I don't remember the details of how STM32 behaves in this regard.)

Comment: I am willing to bet that it is hitting the hard breakpoint instruction associated with semi-hosting, which uses host services via the debugger for stdio and time for example. 
You should ensure semi-hosting is disabled.

Comment: @Lundin due to the Harvard architecture of this part, running code in the data space will severely impair performance, so it would be unusual for an STM32 project to be set up like that.

Comment: Also be sure that the clock source is not a clock output from the debugger.  This may not apply to your situation, but I have run into this issue on Nucleo eval boards.